# How start process and read paramters from stdin input in dart?

Tags: dart, stream, pipe, stdin

I want to implement follow code in dart and start [V2ray](https://github.com/v2fly/v2ray-core)

```
cat ~/.config/qv2ray/vcore/config.json | v2ray
```

This is Node.js implement:

```
const result = child_process.spawn("v2ray", [], { input: str });
```

I spent a whole day solving this problem, but still couldn’t solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made an example on how you can do it:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  final homeDir = getHomeDir();

  if (homeDir == null) {
    throw Exception('Could not find home directory on running platform!');
  }

  final process = await Process.start('v2ray', const []);
  final resultStdoutFuture = process.stdout
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .toList();

  await process.stdin
      .addStream(File('$homeDir/.config/qv2ray/vcore/config.json').openRead());
  await process.stdin.close();

  print('Process stopped with exit code: ${await process.exitCode}');
  print('Returned stdout:');
  (await resultStdoutFuture).forEach((logLine) => print('\t$logLine'));
}

String? getHomeDir() {
  final envVars = Platform.environment;

  if (Platform.isMacOS) {
    return envVars['HOME'];
  } else if (Platform.isLinux) {
    return envVars['HOME'];
  } else if (Platform.isWindows) {
    return envVars['UserProfile'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the question I'm talking about is a bit vague, letting you read a stream from a file. The real situation is to get a json string from the server and pipe this json string to v2ray. Your solution gave me another idea. Now i have solved this problem。my solution follow answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
String server = '''
{
   "field":"config"
}
''';
main() async {
  var v2ray = await Process.start('v2ray', []);
  v2ray.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).forEach(print);
  Stream.value(const Utf8Codec().encode(server)).pipe(v2ray.stdin);
}
```