# Testing stdout and stdin of a Dart console app

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have this simple file:

```
class Console {
  const Console();


  void run() {
    stdout
      ..writeln('Choose:\n')
      ..writeln(' 1) A')
      ..writeln(' 2) B\n')

    final input = stdin.readLineSync() ?? '';

    stdout.write('You have chosen $input');
  }
}
```

How do I unit test this?

---

My best try is the following:

```
test('Making sure that invalid inputs return an error message', () async {
  final process = await Process.start('dart', ['run', r'../bin/demo.dart']);

  process.stdin.write('1');

  process.stdout.transform(Utf8Decoder()).listen(print);
});
```

Since I have no idea on how to check for the `stdout` printed text, I am trying to at least display the strings

```
Choose:
 1) A
 2) B
```

using `transform(Utf8Decoder())` but it's not working. Could you please point me towards the right direction?

**Note**: the main() function is located in `lib/demo.dart` so that's why I'm passing `../bin/demo.dart`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150467/how-start-process-and-read-paramters-from-stdin-input-in-dart